# Insert if not exists avoiding race condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I make sure following statements don't have a race condition?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select col1 from Table1 where SomeId=@SomeId)
INSERT INTO Table1 values (@SomeId,...)

IF NOT EXISTS (select col1 from Table2 where SomeId=@SomeId)
INSERT INTO Table2 values (@SomeId,...)
```

Is this enough

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

BEGIN TRAN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1 FROM Table1 WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE SomeId=@SomeId)
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (@SomeId,...)

COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1 FROM Table2 WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE SomeId=@SomeId)
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (@SomeId,...)

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: What kind of "race condition" are you worried about?  From what I see here, those two insert statements should be completely independent.

Comment: I am worried about the individual if not exist insert statements, wanted to show that they each have their own transaction

Comment: I still don't understand the problem you're trying to solve.  It may be completely obvious to you, but remember - none of us here have been staring over your shoulder.  You need explain the context of your issue.


To answer the question as it stands, with the limited information provided, the second pair of inserts will be in separate explicit transactions.

Comment: @Brian If you check for the existence of a row without locking then another session can insert/update/delete the row before your `insert` executes. Adding `UPDLOCK` and a transaction prevents the race between this session and another user's.

Comment: Thanks, @HABO.  The SQL development that I do doesn't do multi-threaded inserts like that, which is why I didn't grok the question at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  That is enough.  Setting the transaction isolation level to serializable will create key locks that cover `SomeId=@SomeId` when you run your select-- which will prevent other processes from inserting values with the same key (`SomeId=@SomeId`) while your transaction is running.

The `WITH(UPDLOCK)` hint will cause the SELECT to obtain an update lock on the selected row(s), if they exist.  This will prevent other transactions from modifying these rows (if they existed at the time of the select) while your transaction is running.

It doesn't look like you really need the `WITH(UPDLOCK)` hint, since you are committing the transaction right away if the record already exists.  If you wanted to do something else before committing if the record does exist, you might need this hint-- but as it is, it appears you do not.

Comment: Would I need updlock If I selected the inserted row?

Answer (score 0):

A statement is a transaction

```
declare @v int = 11;
insert into iden (val) 
select @v
where not exists (select 1 from iden with (UPDLOCK) where val = @v)
```